# Pyspark mllib + count or collect method throws ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm learning pyspark and mllib.

After predicting the test data using A RF model, I'm assigning the result in a variable called 'predictions' which is a RDD.

If I call predictions.count() or prediction.collect(), then it is failing with the following exception.

Can you please share your thoughts?  Already spent quite some time, but didn't find what is missing.

```
    predictions = predict(training_data, test_data)

  File "/mp5/part_d_poc.py", line 36, in predict

    print(predictions.count())

  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1055, in count

  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1046, in sum

  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 917, in fold

  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 816, in collect

  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__

  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.

: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 28, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
```

I constructed the training data in the following way.

```
raw_training_data.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row.split(',')[-1], Vectors.dense(row.split(',')[0:-1])))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this error is caused when there's a mismatch between the schema and data. Please refer to these -

1. [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with Spark, Spark-Avro and Google Analytics Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235444/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-with-spark-spark-avro-and-google-analytics-data)
2. https://github.com/Azure/spark-cdm-connector/issues/46#issuecomment-717543025
3. https://forums.couchbase.com/t/arrayindexoutofboundsexception/10311/3